# return the data attr in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code returns all elements `li` in html code.
For example:

```
<li data="2" class="produkt_w_koszyku"><b>Audi A6</b> <span class="cena_w_koszyku">199000 zł</span><span style="float: right; margin-right: 30px;" class="deleteitembasket"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span></li><li data="3" class="produkt_w_koszyku"><b>BMW i8</b> <span class="cena_w_koszyku">122 zł</span><span style="float: right; margin-right: 30px;" class="deleteitembasket"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span></li>
```

I would like him to return the value of the datas attribute to me. so: `2, 3`. How can I change this?

```
var $ul = $(this).parents('ul');
localStorage.setItem('item_id', $ul.html());
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('data')`?

Comment: just plain old `data` might be a reserved word. Change it to `data-test` and use the jquery `.data()` method

Comment: Okay, but if there are several of these elements, then I would like the attr data to be written out after the decimal point. for example: `1,2`

Comment: @J.Ga You should edit your question to give a clear example of what you want.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: `$("li.produkt_w_koszyku").map(function(){ return this.getAttribute('data'); }).get().join(',')`

Comment: thank u. ^ it's working

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to loop through the `li` elements and pull the value of an data attribute out. The comments above provide what you need, but to summarize:

```
// you may need a more specific selector, but this works for your html snippet
const dataAttrs = $("li").map(function(){ 
  return $(this).attr('data'); 
}).get().join(',');

// display your data
console.log(dataAttrs);
```

Also, it best to follow the standard wisdom on `data-*` attributes, and rather than using simply `data` doing something such as `data-id`, `data-data`, or whatever. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li.produkt_w_koszyku").map(function(){ return this.getAttribute('data'); }).get().join(',')
```

Select all the elements, map the parts that you want into an array and join them on comma.  You can use `getAttribute()` to get the attribute off of the DOM Element.

Answer (score -1):

You need to prepend your data holding items with data- so like data-data, data-class, data-... as below

```
<article
  id="electriccars"
  data-columns="3"
  data-index-number="12314"
  data-parent="cars">
...
</article>
```

Reading the values of these attributes out in JavaScript is also very simple. You could use getAttribute() with their full HTML name to read them, but the standard defines a simpler way: a DOMStringMap you can read out via a dataset property.

To get a data attribute through the dataset object, get the property by the part of the attribute name after data- (note that dashes are converted to camelCase).

```
var article = document.getElementById('electriccars');

article.dataset.columns // "3"
article.dataset.indexNumber // "12314"
article.dataset.parent // "cars"
```